# Is it possible to unpack a tuple replacing missing elements with None in python?

Tags: python, tuples

I'm wondering if there is a way in python to unpack a tuple replacing missing elements with None.
Here is an example:

```
username, password = credentials.split(':', maxsplit=1)
```

For the `credentials` equal to `root:123456` it returns `('root', '123456')` as expected.
But for `credentials` equal to `root` it throws an exception `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)` as expected as well, but not as I want.
I want it to return `('root', None)` instead. Do you know how to do that?

I could do it like this:

```
credentials_split = credentials.split(':', maxsplit=1)
username, password = credentials_split[0], credentials_split[1] if len(credentials_split) > 1 else None
```

But it's ugly, I'm looking for a better solution.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `str.partition` does almost that for your use case, though it's an empty string instead of `None`.